# initialise string array or 2d char array in derived class in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, arrays

Here's a snippet:

```
class student
   {
    protected:
     string name, subject[6];
      ....
    };
class ugstudent : public student
{
   ...
};
class ugfirst_yr : public ugstudent
{
subject[6] = {"phy", "chem", "math", "electrical", "civil", "comp"};  //error*
 public:
  ...
};
```

*The errors I get for the above initialization: "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier",
 and for the contents in the array: a value of type "const char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "int"

What I want is that the string array subject[] is common, but the contents of the array should differ in each class derived from class ugstudent. What should I change?

Comment: You cannot initialize a data member like that, not even in C++11. By the way, what compiler are you using? The implicit int error message seems very strange.

Comment: If there is no change in behavior between the student types, I would not use inheritance here. Instead pass the subjects as a constructor parameter for student class.

Comment: @NeilKirk Inheritance is required here. It's not seen in this snippet though.
And the vector<string> is not making any difference :( still the same errors!

Comment: Are you allowed to use C++11? What is your compiler.

Comment: However i initialised the subjects in the constructors of the respective derived classes so it worked :)
And I use Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
class student
{
public:
    vector<string> subject;

    student()
    : subject{ "a", "b", "c" }
    {
    }
};
```